# url from Parse to button action

Tags: swift, url, button, parse-platform

I have a PFQueryTableViewController with a custom cell, every cell has 1 label and 1 button, the label(Place) is a text, and the button(Tickets) , when you click it you going to the a url . I have already stored the text for the labels and urls as a strings on Parse.com, but my problem is how I can figure it out to make every button to action and open this stored url from my parse database.

Here is the code

```
class Shows: PFQueryTableViewController {


override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Shows")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    return query  
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ShowsCell
    let showplace = object?.objectForKey("Place") as? String
    let showtickets = object?.objectForKey("Tickets") as? String
    cell.place.text = showplace
    cell.tickets.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.tickets.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ticketsaction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return cell
    }
}
```

And here is the Button Action

```
   @IBAction func ticketsaction(sender: UIButton){

    let ticketsurl = String()
    let url = NSURL(string: "\(ticketsurl)")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it!
I add a `var ticketsurl: String!` in my custom cell ,before the ticketsaction and now looks like this:

```
    var ticketsurl: String!

@IBAction func ticketsaction(sender: UIButton) {
            let url = NSURL(string: "\(ticketsurl)")
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
           }
```

and PFQueryTableView Controller is now looks like this :

```
class Shows: PFQueryTableViewController {


override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
let query = PFQuery(className: "Shows")
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
return query  
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ShowsCell
let showplace = object?.objectForKey("Place") as? String
let showtickets = object?.objectForKey("Tickets") as? String
cell.place.text = showplace
cell.tickets.tag = indexPath.row
cell.ticketsurl = showtickets
return cell
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tag each button with the `indexPath.row` of its cell and grab the specific URL from the array you are using to populate the list. Just equate `button.tag` to `indexPath.row`.

Comment: Thanks for reply! How can I pass the "showtickets" as string in every button action ? After your answer every button print a different number with print(sender.tag), but how can I pass the urls ?

Comment: If you have them in an array, you can use the same number to match one to a button.

Comment: I want to pass showtickets string to tricketsurl string, so every time the button will run 
the block of code from ticketsaction

Comment: I'd probably add all the different `object`s to an array so I can address them in ticketsaction or elsewhere...something like `let showTickets = arrayOfObjects[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Tickets") as? String`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, finally I made it.